# Troubleshoot a systemd service crash because of SystemCallFilter=

Tags: linux, systemd, opensuse

In OpenSUSE `coturn-4.5.2-4.1.x86_64` the `.service` file contains a seemingly generated part with the allowed capabilities and system calls. They're probably trying to sandbox it in case of vulnerabilities. All is fine except the process is killed almost immediately after start and I had to remove all restrictions one by one to find the culprit line:

```
SystemCallFilter=~ ... @privileged ...
```

When the service is killed no useful information is logged to the System Journal.  Only

> Main process exited, code=killed, status=31/SYS

The manual says:

> @privileged   All system calls which need super-user capabilities (capabilities(7))

I actually want to know the actual system call that failed and what capability is missing.

Answer (score 4):

When a service executes a syscall that isn't included in the [`SystemCallFilter=`](https://manpath.be/f35/5/systemd.exec#L1856) set, the default action is that the process is terminated with [`SIGSYS`](https://manpath.be/f35/7/signal#L272), thus the process dumps a core. Thus, you can inspect the corefile and look up the syscall number there.

Example:

```
# coredumpctl debug
(gdb) p $rax
157
```

So `157` is our example syscall number which we can look up in a table, such as:

> https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v5.15/arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_64.tbl

i.e.

```
157 common  prctl           __x64_sys_prctl
```

Thus, `prctl` has to be added to `SystemCallFilter=`.

Another restart might fail because of yet another syscall, thus, it may take some iterations.

You can also check [systemd.exec(5)](https://manpath.be/f35/5/systemd.exec#L1916) for some plausible missing syscall groups that can be added to [`SystemCallFilter=`](https://manpath.be/f35/5/systemd.exec#L2125) to potentially speed up the process.

In addition, one can lookup which syscalls the different groups include exactly in the currently running systemd via:

```
systemd-analyze syscall-filter
```

---

In case the service file also contains `SystemCallErrorNumber=` then you have to remove it in order to let the process core dump.